# Japanese calendar date picker are greyed out

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

When I used Japanese calendar in my date picker, many year columns was greyed out although these are available dates.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rDOP.png)

```
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:
                            NSCalendarIdentifierJapanese];
    datePicker.calendar = calendar;
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self.textField setInputView:datePicker];
    [self.textField reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: Works no problem - if I configure it in code or storyboard, use wheels or default, it just works. I think the problem is not the Japanese calendar but something else.

Comment: This is my sample project: [link] https://github.com/HaLanHuynh/DatePickerTest
Please scroll up to see the years that are not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should set setMinimumDate for the datePicker